# Падежи прилагательного

Tags: падежи

Здравствуйте. Никак не могу разобраться с падежами прилагательных.

Например в предложении: Лодка была сухая.

Как правильно подобрать падеж? 
"Лодка была сухой" или "Лодка была сухая"?

"Даже сухая лодка была тяжелой" или "Даже сухая лодка была тяжелая"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Речь,как я поняла, идёт об именной части составного именного сказуемого, выраженной именем прилагательным.    В именной части сказуемого творительный падеж прилагательного (как и существительного) - активно утверждающаяся в современном языке форма.Она "отодвигает" на второй план прилагательное в именительном падеже.
Основные различия в их употреблении зависят ещё и от формально - грамматических условий.
Прилагательное в Т.п. имеет книжный характер, традиционно выражает признак, присущий предмету в данный, определённый момент (Помню, в Ваши годы я был хмурЫМ, неприветливЫМ(Т.п.))
 Прилагательное в И.п. традиционно выражает признак вневременного, постоянного характера, заложенный в предмете. (Вода в озере была прозрачнАЯ(И.п.). Характер у него был железнЫЙ(И.п.))
Поэтому лодка была сухОЙ(признак временный). Даже сухая лодка была тяжёлАЯ(признак постоянный)
 Ю.А.Бельчиков, Практическая стилистика современного русского языка.-2-е изд., М.:Аст - Пресс Книга, 2012, с.231 - 232

Хочу отметить, что этот вопрос уже поднимался на сайте.Указанные свойства именительного и творительного предикативного рассматриваются автором пособия как преимущественная тенденция и не имеют в речевой практике безусловного, категорического характера.

Comment: Благодарю. Кажется, разобрался.

Answer (score 3):

Примеры авторского решения задачи:

1) Лодка **была сухая**. Обозначаем признак как вневременной (на данный момент видно, что лодка сухая). Пример У Бельчикова: Вода в озере **была прозрачная**.

2) Даже сухая лодка **была тяжелой**. Этот признак фиксируется как отнесенный ко времени со значением "**оказалась** тяжелой".

Comment: Вне контекста трудно судить, поэтому Вы можете быть правы с такой же степенью вероятности, как и я.

Comment: Кроме того, Вы сами подчёркиваете, что лодка сухая только на ДАННЫЙ МОМЕНТ! Как же признак может быть вневременным? Не надо себе противоречить!

Comment: Решение по выбору падежа И.п. или Т.п. часто бывает авторским, поэтому я говорю не о правильности или неправильности выбора,  а о том, как бы написала я. Текст я представляю примерно так: Подходим к берегу  и видим лодку, она сухая,  нам кажется, что мы можем легко ее сдвинуть, но она  оказывается тяжелой (тяжелее, чем думали). Постоянство признака здесь вещь относительная и применимо только к развитию данного сюжета.

Comment: Значит, как я понял, однозначного ответа быть не может? Автор решает сам, какой падеж уместнее?

Comment: Есть определенные рекомендации, но они не абсолютного характера. Можно выбрать падеж интуитивно, но затем объяснить свой выбор с учетом этих рекомендаций.  В частности,  характер признака (постоянный или временный) вы можете определять с авторской точки зрения.  У Розенталя  есть информация  на эту тему:  §179. Формы сказуемого  http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/62.htm